# Jquery random slideshow loop before repeating

Tags: jquery, random, slideshow

I have the following slideshow which displays a slide at random when you click the button. However I would like it to show all of the slides before repeating any, for example: 3,1,2,4,5 2,1,4,5,3 - the user sees all of the slides before any are repeated, instead of what happens now: 2,3,4,2,1,2,4,5 the user has already seen slide 2 three times before seeing slide 5. I think maybe using an array would do it but I'm not sure how to implement this. Any help is much appreciated!

```
var slides = $('div.slide');
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length);
slides.eq(rand).addClass('active');

$("a.btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $active = $('#sliderInner div.slide.active');

    var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(400,function(){//fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
    });
});
```

I have also tried this but it does the same thing:

```
var slides = $('div.slide');
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length);
slides.eq(rand).addClass('active');

$("a.btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var grp = $("#sliderInner").children();

    Array.prototype.sort.call(grp, function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
    });

    $('#sliderInner').empty().append(grp);

    var $active = $('#sliderInner div.slide.active');

    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#sliderInner div:first');
    $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(400,function(){//fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
    });
});
```

Comment: Put possible values (1-5) into an array, shuffle it, and take the first, second, … element out of it. After you’ve iterated of the whole array once, shuffle it again.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see what you mean although as I'm relatively new to javascript I'm not sure I understand how to do this with the code I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I have found a solution, maybe not the most elegant but it works. In case it's useful to anyone in the future:

```
var slides = $('div.slide');
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length);
slides.eq(rand).addClass('active');

$("a.btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $active = $('#sliderInner div.slide.active');


    var $sibs  = $active.siblings().not('.used');
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

    $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(400,function(){//fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active').addClass('used');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
    });

    if ($active.siblings().length-1 == $(".used").length) {
        $('.slide').removeClass('used');
        $active.fadeOut(400,function(){//fade out the top image
            $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active').removeClass('used');
        });
        }


});
```